# Function inside a function: why does this echo statement only display once?

Tags: php

In the following code, why does the phrase "example" only output once if both foo() and bar() are called>

```
<?php
function foo() 
{
    function bar() 
    {
        echo "example\n";
    }
}

foo();

bar();

?>
```

Comment: Because with `foo()` you only call `foo()` and not `bar()`. You only call `bar()` once. Your code is basically: `function foo(){} function bar(){echo "example";} foo(); bar();`

Comment: Have `foo` call `bar`.

Comment: Why did you declare a function inside other function?

Answer (score 1):

You want to be declaring your functions separately like so:

```
<?php
function foo() 
{
    bar();
}

function bar() 
{
    echo "example\n";
}

foo();

bar();

?>
```

Nesting your functions inside each other doesn't really serve any purpose that i can think of.